# How can I accomplish layer composites in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, layers

I am trying to learn few tricks from Photoshop CS6 to accomplish something different and make look cool. I'm interested to know how to accomplish this

http://www.flickr.com/photos/nhanusek/3506460132/

[image]

I'm interested to know some tutorial document, name of the technique, some examples, things i should be focusing while taking picture :)

Answer (score 2):

When shooting, make sure the lighting is similar for best results.  It wouldn't surprise me if the photo of her standing up was taken right before or after the main one in the same place.

Then, it is a matter of removing the background from the photo that you want to nest in.  It can be done with some automated techniques if the background is a different color from the subject (using the magic select tool) or can be manually painted out by erasing the background from a layer that it is on.

This new subject only layer can be scaled and positioned over the background plate so that the positioning is correct and then some shadows are either painted in or projected in based on the shape of the layer and a light source direction.  Some other minor airbrushing changes might be done to help blend the image together better, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

As AJ said, lighting is key. You need all the source images to be taken with light from the same direction, strength and temperature, as much as possible.

Another key thing is to add realistic shadows.  That really helps sell the image and make it look real.

Matt Kloskowski has a booking on [Photoshop Compositing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321808231) that will tell you everything you need to know about lighting, setting up the shots, extracting from backgrounds, adding shadows and other effects, and polishing the images.